# What was that snake in Jabba's dungeon that grabbed C-3PO by the neck?

Tags: star-wars, return-of-the-jedi

When C-3PO and R2-D2 were being taken down into Jabba's Dungeon, what was that snake creature that grabbed C-3PO by the neck?

[image: C-3PO seemingly getting grabbed around the neck by an arm thick tentacle that emerged from behind.]

Comment: There is a name for it!

Comment: Perhaps it's listed under "things our Mothers warned us about" wiki?

Comment: I felt that my answer to this one was pretty comprehensive. Is there anything else you'd like me to add before considering an acceptance?

Comment: Just a regular standard dungeon snake.

Answer (score 21):

### Main Canon

**This creature doesn't have a name.**

- The [junior novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_VI:_Return_of_the_Jedi_%28junior_novelization%29) refers to it as a "*long tentacle*"...

> “How horrid!” Trying to avoid the hand, he moved to the other side of
> the passage. A **long tentacle** snaked out from between the bars of
> another cell door, and C-3PO felt the tentacle wrap around his neck.
>
> “Ohh!” he wailed as he pulled himself free.

- The new (and fully Disney canon) [junior novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Return_of_the_Jedi:_Beware_the_Power_of_the_Dark_Side!) has no more relevant information, referring to it as a "*tentacle*".

> “What could possibly have come over Master Luke?” chatters C-3PO. “Is it something I did? He never expressed any unhappiness with my work. Oh! How horrid! Ohh!”
> A tentacle has reached out from a filthy cell they are passing and wrapped itself around C-3PO’s neck.
> The Gamorrean pounds it with a big fist. The tentacle jerks back into the cell, releasing C-3PO, who spins and totters awkwardly down the stone corridor after R2-D2.

- The [James Khan novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_VI:_Return_of_the_Jedi_%28novel%29) is similarly unhelpful, referring to it as a "*tentacle*"

> Artoo and Threepio marched dismally through the dank passageway at the
> prodding of a Gamorrean guard. Dungeon cells lined both walls. The
> unspeakable cries of anguish that emanated from within as the droids
> passed echoed off the stone and down the endless catacombs.
> Periodically a hand or claw or **tentacle** would reach through the bars
> of a door to grab at the hapless robots.

- The film's [screenplay](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-Return-of-the-Jedi.html) refers to it as a "*large tentacle*"

> **9 - INT DUNGEON CORRIDOR**
>
> **THREEPIO:** *What could possibly have come over Master Luke. Is it
> something I did?  He never expressed any unhappiness with my work. Oh!
> Oh! Hold it! Ohh!*
>
> A **large tentacle** wraps around Threepio's neck. He manages to break
> free, and they move on to a door at the end of the corridor.

LucasFilm have identified the language that was spoken during this encounter as '[Borish](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Borish)'. It's certainly possible that the creature was [a Bor](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Mairan#:%7E:text=Mairan%2C%20also%20referred%20to%20as%20Bors%2C) (e.g. since a Bor might speak Bor*ish*), of which the [Bor Gullett](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Bor_Gullet) is an example. They don't look especially similar, but they do have tentacles and it's possible that the one in Jabba's palace was unwell.

---

### EU Canon

The [Star Wars: Complete Locations](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0756614198) book offers a somewhat fuzzy glimpse at this individual and refers to him as "**Tentacled Prisoner**"

[image]

Comment: I know but what was that

Comment: Dunno. I'm still working on it.

Comment: I think it was a Florn Lamproid

Comment: @MarcusS.Whitelock - [unlikely](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lamproid). The appearance is dissimilar

Comment: I quite like the idea that _something_ in Star Wars doesn't have a name and a full backstory on Wookiepedia.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - Give it time and it'll have its own mini-series

Comment: @Valorum: the official Dungeon Snake Cosy Neck-Warmers would be this season's must-have holiday gift.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - Plush baby tentacle monster