# What was the clawed hand that tried to grab C-3PO in Jabba's palace?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, return-of-the-jedi

In the scene where C-3PO walks through the dungeon corridor a creature puts its clawed hand through the bars of its cell, startling C-3PO.

[image]

**Is this creature ever identified, perhaps in the Expanded Universe (Legends)?**

Comment: Patrial dupe of http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/90034/what-was-that-snake-in-jabbas-dungeon-that-grabbed-c-3po-by-the-neck

Comment: So what? The question is still different

Comment: Indeed. Perhaps it would be worth editing to focus on the question that is not answered elsewhere, though.

Comment: @HasanHadžić - It matters because your question is a duplicate and we don't ask duplicates :-) I've edited out the dupe part

Comment: [Why are some questions marked as duplicate?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates).

Answer (score 5):

**The novelisation isn't much help**

> *Periodically **a hand or claw** or tentacle **would reach through the bars
>   of a door to grab at the hapless robots.***
>
> <sub><sup>[Return of the Jedi - Official Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_VI:_Return_of_the_Jedi_(novel))</sup></sub>

**Nor is the film's junior novel**

> *“What could possibly have come over Master Luke?” C-3PO wondered aloud. “Is it something I did? He never expressed any unhappiness with my work.” **C-3PO saw a repulsive hand reach out between the bars of a cell door and try to grab him.**   “Oh! Oh!” the protocol droid exclaimed. “How horrid!” Trying to avoid the hand, he moved to the other side of the passage.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Return of the Jedi - Junior Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_VI:_Return_of_the_Jedi_(junior_novelization))</sup></sub>

**The script isn't any use**

> One of Jabba's Gamorrean guards marches Artoo and Threepio down a
>   dank,  shadowy passageway lined with holding cells. The cries of
>   unspeakable  creatures bounce off the cold stone walls. **Occasionally a
>   repulsive arm  or tentacle grabs through the bars** at the hapless
>   droids. Artoo beeps  pitifully.
>
> <sub><sup>[Return of the Jedi - Screenplay](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-Return-of-the-Jedi.html)</sup></sub>

**It doesn't even get a mention in the new junior novel**

> *"What could possibly have come over Master Luke?” chatters C-3PO. “Is it something I did? He never expressed any unhappiness with my work. Oh! How horrid! Ohh!”
>
>   A tentacle has reached out from a filthy cell they are passing and wrapped itself around C-3PO’s neck.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Return of the Jedi - Beware the Power of the Dark Side!](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Return_of_the_Jedi:_Beware_the_Power_of_the_Dark_Side!)</sup></sub>

The [Complete Locations](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Complete_Locations_(2016)) book merely refers to it as a one of several "***Captive[s] awaiting torture***".

[image]